# Formik + Yup - How to validate the value of the input itself with another one?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, yup

I would like to do the following validation:

- If it was necessary to inform a coupon, the error message would appear, but even with the following code this is not possible.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

export type FormValues = {
  promotionalCode: string;
  requirePromotionalCode: boolean;
};

export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  requirePromotionalCode: yup.boolean(),
  promotionalCode: yup.string().when('requirePromotionalCode', {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required('Please, enter a coupon'),
    otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
  }),
});
```

I tried as follows, but nothing worked.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

export type FormValues = {
  promotionalCode: string;
  requirePromotionalCode: boolean;
};

export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  requirePromotionalCode: yup.boolean(),
  promotionalCode: yup.string().when('requirePromotionalCode', {
    is: (requirePromotionalCode, promotionalCode) =>
      requirePromotionalCode && !promotionalCode,
    then: yup.string().required('Please, enter a coupon'),
    otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make Yup.when work properly, you would have to add promotionalCode and and requirePromotionalCode to initialValues and to your Yup schema shape.

In general, when using validationSchema, it is best practices to ensure that all of you form's fields have initial values so that Yup can see them immediately.

The result would look like:

<Formik
initialValues={{ promotionalCode : '', requirePromotionalCode: false }}
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
...

Comment: I added them to initialValues, but they are not in this file

Comment: It does not matter in which file they are

Comment: I agree, the point is: even using initialValues correctly, validation does not work

Answer (score 0):

In many cases `.test()` would work ([read the docs here](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema)).

This is the example to solve the problem:

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';

export type FormValues = {
  promotionalCode: string;
  requirePromotionalCode: boolean;
};

export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  requirePromotionalCode: yup.boolean(),
  promotionalCode: yup.string().test(
    'requirePromotionalCode',
    'Please, enter a coupon',
    (value, context) => context.requirePromotionalCode && !!value
  ),
});
```

Things to note, `.test()` expects the value `true` to pass the 'test', so the return value should be true when the `requirePromotionalCode` is true and promotionalCode `value` is not empty.

Otherwise, the error message in the second argument would be thrown.

Hope it helps!